# failed to take the data from sqlitebase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am new to android. 
i got error on this line:

```
 return database.insert(DBHelper.tableName, null, initialValues);
```

it said:

```
07-16 09:46:51.179: E/SQLiteLog(303): (1) no such table: LesClient
07-16 09:46:51.289: E/SQLiteDatabase(303): Error inserting RaisonSocial=SARL A D I P A Ville=   SAINT HERBLAIN CEDEX CodeClient=850012 Tel=02 40 92 21 2
07-16 09:46:51.289: E/SQLiteDatabase(303): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LesClient (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LesClient(RaisonSocial,Ville,CodeClient,Tel) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

why my my table is not exist ?

i have created here:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.w(TAG, TABLE_CREATE);
  boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();       
  if (dbExists) {
    // do nothing

  } else {
    DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
    DB.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

}
```

here is my code complete,
DBHelper Class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "FAEXPED";
    public static final int version = 3;
    public static Context currentContext;
    public static String tableName = "LesClient";

    public static final String KEY_CodeClient = "CodeClient";
    public static final String KEY_RsNom = "RaisonSocial";
    public static final String KEY_Ville = "Ville";
    public static final String KEY_Tel = "Tel"; 

    private static final String TAG = "Create_The_DB";

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            tableName + " ( "+ KEY_CodeClient + " VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "+ KEY_RsNom +"  VARCHAR," + KEY_Ville + "  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Tel +"  VARCHAR)";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        //super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(context, DBName, null, version);
        currentContext = context;
        DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.w(TAG, TABLE_CREATE);
      boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();       
      if (dbExists) {
        // do nothing

      } else {
        DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
        DB.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                 + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
              onCreate(db);

    }

    private boolean checkDbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

}

Controller Class:

```
public class SQLController {

    private DBHelper dbhelper;
    private Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SQLController(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;
    }

    public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(ourcontext);
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> ReadData() {
            try {

                Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.tableName, null);

                if (c != null ) {
                    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String LeCodeClient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_CodeClient));
                            String LeRsNom = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_RsNom));
//                          String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(""));
//                          String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                            //int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                            results.add("Code CL: " + LeCodeClient + ",RS: " + LeRsNom);
                        }while (c.moveToNext());
                    } 
                }


            } catch (SQLiteException se ) { 
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
            } finally {
//              if (database != null) 
//                  database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DBHelper.tableName);
//              database.close();
            }
            return results;

        }

    public long createItmes(String LeCodeClient, String LeRsNom, String LeVille, String LeTel) {

          ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
          initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CodeClient, LeCodeClient);
          initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_RsNom, LeRsNom);
          initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Ville, LeVille);
          initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Tel, LeTel);


          return database.insert(DBHelper.tableName, null, initialValues);
         }

    public void insertSomeItmes() {  
    createItmes("850007","A B S","MONTAIGU","02 51 94 18 46");
    createItmes("850012","SARL A D I P A"," SAINT HERBLAIN CEDEX","02 40 92 21 2");
    createItmes("850024","AIZENAY AUTO","AIZENAY","02 51 94 60 40");    
    createItmes("850034","AMS","OLONNE SUR MER","02 51 95 05 23");
    createItmes("850042","ETS ARMOUET","LES HERBIERS","02 51 92 98 59");
     }  
}
```

and last but not least, the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLController   dbcon = new SQLController(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        InsertTheData();
        GetData();
        displayResultList();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displayResultList() {
        TextView tView = new TextView(this);
        tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
                "of the results are displayed");
        getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }

    private ArrayList<String> GetData()
    {
        try {           
             dbcon.open();
             results = (ArrayList<String>) dbcon.ReadData();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not Read data");
        }
         finally {         
            dbcon.close();
         }
        return results;
    }

    private void InsertTheData()
    {
        try {           
             dbcon.open();
             dbcon.insertSomeItmes();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not Insert data");
        }
         finally {          
            dbcon.close();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: first, add the following part to onCreate(), and not outside it: SQLController   dbcon = new SQLController(this);

Comment: I don't understand one thing. When you are using sqliteopenhelper, so why you implemented if...else condition for checking DB is present or not. Because it gives you onCreate & onUpgrade method. Those handle functionality of checking DB present or not & you already wrote that query for dropping table if exists. First make these changes. I guess because of this, it not creating table.

Comment: Thanks you for all of yours respond, i follow them. but now i got Database Lock message.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` incorrectly.

Get rid of all the hardcoded paths and `checkDbExists()` logic. The superclass already handles things like that for you.

Then make `onCreate()` just execute the SQL to create your table and nothing more.

Finally uninstall your app so that the old database file is removed and `onCreate()` gets run once.

Comment: there is the Controller class(which makes it a nested structure) in which the DbHelper and other methods are included...which normally is called directly from the activity. Except that, won't his code work properly with the context declared properly (?)

Answer (score 0):

Think your problem is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLController   dbcon = new SQLController(this);  //this part
```

Declaring that before/outside `onCreate()` is fine but initializing every part which contains the `context` or `activity` must be done inside `onCreate()`

Initialize it the following way, and should work fine..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SQLController   dbcon = new SQLController(this);
        //rest of the code
    }
```

Right now, the `DbHelper` which is inside SQLController doesn't create the database/table, hence the error that `LesClient` isn't found